# The Select Box value should be access in multiple pages

Tags: php

I have a select box with dates. When selecting the dates it will display a particular invoice with the date that was selected.Up to this it works fine. 
What I need is if I go to another page and come back, the select box should be selected with the data that I selected previously.

Answer (score 0):

Use get method. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). Upon submit, just set your the date on your url redirection then. Then use get method to get the value of the date. Try code below.

```
$_POST['date'] = $date;

header('location: currentpage.php?date={$date}');
```

Then when getting back to the form, check if the variable for get method exists, if it exists, check if option is equal to date submitted.

```
<select name="date">
    <option 
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
            if ($_GET['date'] == '12-25-12') { echo "selected"; }
        }
    ?>
    >12-25-12</option>
</select>
```